# I tried to read string from file and store it in Excel sheet

Tags: java, string, excel

this is what i have tried

```
public class UniqueUSER

{

     static HSSFWorkbook hwb=new HSSFWorkbook();

     static HSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("new sheet");

     public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException

    {

     HSSFRow row;

     HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<>();

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("Sample.log"));

     PrintStream out=new PrintStream("D:/Excel.xls");

     String str=null;

     while((str=br.readLine())!=null)

     {

     if(str.contains("FLTR"))
     {

         String user=str.substring(97, 135);

                 names.add(user);

                 HSSFRow row1 =  sheet.createRow((short)count);

     }
}

Iterator itr=names.iterator(); 

while(itr.hasNext())
{  

    out.println(itr.next());  

}

}

}
```

This program storing values to excel sheet but when i read same file using following program, I am getting exception and errors..

```
public class Country1
 {

    private String name;

        private String shortCode;

    public Country1(String n, String c)

        {
        this.name=n;

                this.shortCode=c;

        }

    public void Country(String name2, String shortCode2) 

        {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        }

    public String getName() 

        {

          return name;

        }

        public void setName(String name) 

        {

                this.name = name;
    }

        public String getShortCode() 

        {

            return shortCode;

        }

        public void setShortCode(String shortCode) 

        {

            this.shortCode = shortCode;

        }

    @Override

        public String toString()

        {

            return name + "::" + shortCode;

        }

}

public class ReadExcel

{

    public static List<Country1> readExcelData(String fileName)

    {
        List<Country1> countriesList = new ArrayList<Country1>();

        try 

                {

                    //Create the input stream from the xlsx/xls file

                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

            //Create Workbook instance for xlsx/xls file input stream

                    Workbook workbook = null;

                    if(fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith("xlsx"))

                        {

                           workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

                        }

                        else if(fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith("xls"))

                        {

                            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

                        }

            //Get the number of sheets in the xlsx file

                         int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();

            //loop through each of the sheets

                        for(int i=0; i < numberOfSheets; i++)

                        {

                //Get the nth sheet from the workbook

                    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);

                //every sheet has rows, iterate over them

                    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 

                        {

                    String name = "";

                    String shortCode = "";

                //Get the row object

                        Row row = rowIterator.next();

                  //Every row has columns, get the column iterator and iterate over them
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 

                                {

                                 //Get the Cell object

                                 Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                        //check the cell type and process accordingly

                                 switch(cell.getCellType())

                                 {

                                   case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

                                   if(shortCode.equalsIgnoreCase(""))

                                   {

                                    shortCode = cell.getStringCellValue().trim();

                                   }

                                   else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))

                                   {
                                //2nd column
                            name = cell.getStringCellValue().trim();

                                   }

                                  else
                                  {
                                //random data, leave it
                               System.out.println("Randomdata::"+cell.getStringCellValue());

}

break;


case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

System.out.println("Random data::"+cell.getNumericCellValue());

}

} //end of cell iterator

Country1 c = new Country1(name, shortCode);

countriesList.add(c);

} //end of rows iterator


} //end of sheets for loop

//close file input stream
fis.close();

} 

catch (IOException e) 

{

e.printStackTrace();

}

return countriesList;

}

public static void main(String args[])

{

    List<Country1> list = readExcelData("D:\\Excel.xls");

    System.out.println("Country List\n"+list);

}

}
```

I am confused which program is correct and which one is wrong.. please someone could help me.. thanks lot

Exception are like below:

```
Unable to read entire header; 320 bytes read; expected 512 bytes
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.alertShortRead(HeaderBlock.java:227)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.readFirst512(HeaderBlock.java:208)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:104)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:128)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:342)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:323)
    at com.unisys.ReadExcel.readExcelData(ReadExcel.java:32)
    at com.unisys.ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:97)
```

Country List

[]

Comment: so is the file OK if you open it with an external application e.g. excel?

Comment: @ScaryWombat.. firstit shows dialog that.."the file you are opening is in different format than specified by file extension. Verify that file is not corrupted and is from trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open file now?"

Comment: so it is the writing of the file that is bad, see my answer

Comment: @Scary...you mean that my program to write contents to file is wrong?.. thanks you but how can i fix that?... even i followed as you specified..

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
```

to

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator()
```

Also, when writing your create rows, but you do not write anything to them

```
HSSFRow row1 =  sheet.createRow((short)count);
```

then create cell

```
row.createCell (0).setCellValue (user);
```

**Update**

Just had another look at your code, why on earth are you doing

```
PrintStream out=new PrintStream("D:/Excel.xls");
```

Use the POI API to create the xls.

Comment: @Scary...yeah I have edited it but still i am getting same exception